# how to stop selenium exiting instantly and fix not typing keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, webautomation

just what the title states, it opens the site for a split second and exits; it also doesn't type what it is supposed to type. how do i fix this?

i've already tried numerous methods to find the element, and i'm pretty sure it's correct. correct me if im wrong, but i dont think there's nothing wrong. also, chromedriver matches with my chrome version and is on my path variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
username = "ASDASD"

url = "https://www.stealmylogin.com/demo.html" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome() driver.get(url)

driver.find_elementfind_element("username").send_keys(username)
```

Comment: you need to [use By.NAME](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models/) to select element by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, ""), and use the attribute of type to find different element.

view the document https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#find-elements-from-element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
username = "ASDASD"
driverpath = r"C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\6\msedgedriver.exe"
service=Service(executable_path=driverpath)
url = "https://www.stealmylogin.com/demo.html" 
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = service)
driver.get(url)

kk = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
for i in range(len(kk)):
    elt = kk[i]
    typek = elt.get_attribute('type')
    if typek and typek=='text':
        elt.send_keys(username)
    elif typek and typek=='password':
        elt.send_keys(username)
    else:
        elt.click()
```

this is the page source

```
<form action="https://example.com" method="post">
username:
<br>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
password:
<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```